# How to parse multiple JSON arrays using JSON.parse()?

Tags: arrays, json

I am getting records from db and creating an array for each row and encoding it using `json_encode()`. 
Now, my data is returned as follows : `[{"slug":"bitcoin","change7d":"-3.87"}][{"slug":"maker","change7d":"-8.58"}]`.

When i am trying to parse the data on ajax call, `console.log()` returns error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 39`. Here is my code:

in my php file:

```
    foreach($result as $row){
        $data[] = $row;

    }
    print json_encode($data);
```

in my js file:

```
    var newData = JSON.parse(result);
```

If i change my query a bit and get a single record, then I have no trouble parsing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researching, I managed to solve the issue by simply doing this:

```
var old = JSON.stringify(result).replace(/\]\[/g, ",");
var newData = JSON.parse(old);

console.log(newData);
```

It replaces all the occurrence of '][' with ',' hence converting the response data as Valid JSON.

and it gives the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse parses a single valid JS object (either { } structure or array). So, solution in your case either fetch array by array from database and parse them one by one, or try to convert them into one big array of arrays at the text level you get from database. In order to do that you need to surround your arrays with square brackets and put commas between them.

In your case it will look like:

```
  [
    [{"slug":"bitcoin","change7d":"-3.87"}],
    [{"slug":"maker","change7d":"-8.58"}]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are parsing is invalid. You should return a single array of objects to parse data properly, instead of two arrays. E. g.:

```
[{"slug":"bitcoin","change7d":"-3.87"},{"slug":"maker","change7d":"-8.58"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a single array containing the records, try simply

`print json_encode($result)`

in your PHP file